# Jest simulate 'click' works quirky and test fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a simple component, that looks like this

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styles from './styles.css'

export class App extends PureComponent {
  handleClick = (event) => {

    const { loadGreetings } = this.props
    loadGreetings()
  }

  render () {
    const { hi } = this.props
    return (
      <section>
        <h1 className={styles.earlyDawn}>{hi}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Handshake</button>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  hi: PropTypes.string,
  loadGreetings: PropTypes.func
}

export default App
```

Here is my test file

```
import React from 'react'
import {App} from './index'
import {shallow} from 'Enzyme'

describe('Testing App container...', () => {
  let props

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      loadGreetings: jest.fn().mockName('loadGreetings'),
      hi: 'Hi from test'
    }
  })

  test('should handle click on the button', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App {...props}/>)
    const buttonHi = wrapper.find('button')
    const instance = wrapper.instance()

    expect(buttonHi.length).toBe(1)

    jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleClick')
    buttonHi.simulate('click')

    expect(props.loadGreetings).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(instance.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

})
```

So the problem is in the second toHaveBeenCalled assertion that fails all the time. However, first toHaveBeenCalled seems to be working, which bothers me, because props.loadGreetings is called inside instance.handleClick. Could you please help me to find what may be the problem?

Dependencies: "react": "16.9.0", "react-dom": "16.9.0", "babel-jest": "^24.8.0", "enzyme": "^3.10.0", "jest": "^24.8.0",

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to pass in some initial props and test your component based upon those initial props -- you'll also manipulate those props to add more assertions.

Here's a working example (click on the `Tests` tab to run the tests):

[image: Edit Testing Button Click]

---

**components/App/index.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class App extends PureComponent {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.loadGreetings();
  };

  render() {
    const { message } = this.props;
    return (
      <section className="app">
        <h1>{message}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Handshake</button>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string,
  loadGreetings: PropTypes.func
};

export default App;
```

**components/App/App.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import App from "./index";

// define the passed in function here for easier testing below
const loadGreetings = jest.fn();

// initial props to pass into 'App'
const initProps = {
  message: "hi",
  loadGreetings
};

describe("Testing App container...", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    // this resets the wrapper with initial props defined above
    wrapper = shallow(<App {...initProps} />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // this clears any calls to the mocked function 
    // and thereby resets it 
    loadGreetings.mockClear();
  });

  it("renders without errors", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".app").exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(loadGreetings).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });

  it("initially renders a 'hi' message and then a 'goodbye' message", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("h1").text()).toEqual("hi");

    // manipulating the initial 'message' prop
    wrapper.setProps({ message: "goodbye" });

    expect(wrapper.find("h1").text()).toEqual("goodbye");
  });

  it("should call 'loadGreetings' when the 'Handshake' button is clicked", () => {    
    // since we passed in 'loadGreetings' as a jest function
    // we expect it to be called when the 'Handshake' button is
    // clicked
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(loadGreetings).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

---

Not recommended (see below), but you can spy on the class method -- you'll have to work with instances, forceUpdate the instance, then invoke the handleClick method either manually, `wrapper.instance().handleClick()`, or indirectly via some element's event handler: `wrapper.find("button").simulate("click")` or `wrapper.find("button").props().onClick()`.

The reason I don't recommend this testing strategy is that you're testing a React implementation (testing whether or not the element's event handler invokes your callback function). Instead, you can avoid that by asserting against whether or not a prop function is called and/or a prop/state change happens. This is a more standard and direct approach to testing the component -- as that is what we care about; we care that the props and/or state changes based upon some user action. In other words, by making assertions against the 'loadGreetings' prop being called we're already testing that the onClick event handler works.

Working example:

[image: Edit Testing Button Click - Example 2]

**App.test.js** (same testing as above, with the exception of this test):

```
  it("should call 'loadGreetings' when the 'Handshake' button is clicked", () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "handleClick"); // spying on the method class
    wrapper.instance().forceUpdate(); // required to ensure the spy is placed on the method
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    const mockedFn = jest.fn(); // setting the method as a mocked fn()
    wrapper.instance().handleClick = mockedFn;
    wrapper.instance().forceUpdate(); // required to update the method instance with a mocked fn
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");

    expect(mockedFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt, for your explicit answer. Yes I know that it is simpler to test props, but my question was about the malfunction of simulate 'click' behavior. I'm trying to understand why jest doesn't recognize instance.handleClick call, when it should.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but it unnecessary for testing purposes as React already handles callback functions in the onClick handler. So testing for React implementations is redundant and not worthwhile. That said, if you want to spy on a class method, then see the updated answer above.